# CSS Sticky Grouped Table Headers

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm using React Bootstrap for building my table. The table has grouped headers (two rows of headers). Issue is I can't seem to figure out how to make both header rows sticky. I only got one down so far. Currently, only the top row is fixed.

```
<div className="wrapper-table">
  <Table className="table-expand" hover size="sm">
    <thead className="tableHeader">
      <tr className="firstHead">
        <th className="cell-1" colSpan="12">CMF Results: {row.cmfResults} (Processed with Errors)</th>
      </tr>
      <tr className="secondHead">
        <th className="cell-2">#</th>
        <th className="cell-5">TradeReportID</th>
        <th className="cell-6">SecurityID</th>
        <th className="cell-7">Account</th>
        <th className="cell-8">TradeReportRejectReason</th>
        <th className="cell-9">Text</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      ...data
    </tbody>
  </Table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .wrapper-table {
      max-height: 400px;
      overflow: auto; 
      thead tr.firstHead th, thead tr.firstHead td{
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
      }
      thead tr.secondHead th, thead tr.secondHead td{
        position: sticky;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Try to set thead itself sticky. :)

Comment: https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gOPpxjP a base to test from sticky thead